# Set iPhone XS SceneKit PixelFormat to MTKView format MTLPixelFormatRGB10A8_2P_XR10_sRGB

Tags: swift, scenekit, metal

I have a SceneKit Scene running on a iPhone XS, the PixelFormat is coming back as: `MTLPixelFormatRGB10A8_2P_XR10_sRGB`

I'm trying to set a `MTKView` to be the same format, but I'm unable to find a `MTLPixelFormat` that could match it. The closest one looks like `bgr10_xr_srgb` - but it's not a match.

The only way I can get matching pixelFormats is to add the following to my plist

```
<key>SCNDisableWideGamut</key>
<true/>
```

But of course, it isn't preferred as it sets the format as `bgr10a2Unorm`

Anyone else running into a similar issue?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Or in other words, why do you need the `MTKView` to have the same pixel format?